# let $G$ is finite group and has a unique maximal subgroup $H$, show that it is cyclic.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

let $G$ is finite group and has a unique maximal subgroup $H$, show that it is cyclic.

we are given hint that consider an  element of $G/ H$

but i am not able to relate this hint to the question .any suggestion

thank in advanced.

Comment: The hint stems from the following theorem: "A normal subgroup $N$ of a group $G$ is a maximal normal subgroup if and only if the quotient $G/N$ is simple."

Comment: BTW, the wording of this question is exceedingly ambiguous.Are you asking whether $G$ is cyclic, or whether $H$ is cyclic?